# what's wrong with this code to use clojure.java.jdbc/insert

Tags: clojure, insert

I tried to use java.jdbc insert! function, which can receive multiple objects.
the `clojure.java.jdbc/insert!` should be called like this:

```
(clojure.java.jdbc/insert! db {:name "john" :password "123"} {:name "george" :password "234"})
```

I defined a function to do add multiple user records:

```clj
(defn add-users [user & more]
   (-add-users db-spec user more))

(defmacro -add-users
   ([db user] `(j/with-db-connection [con-db# db]
                           (j/insert! con-db# ~user)))
   ([db user & more] (let [users (-mk-user-list user more)]
                       `(j/with-db-connection [con-db# db]
                          (j/insert! con-db# ~@(flatten users)))))
(defmacro -mk-usre-list
  ([user] `~user)
  ([user & more] `(list ~user (-mk-user-list ~@more))))
```

when I macroexpand the -add-users, looks the result is ok like this:

```clj
=> (macroexpand '(-add-users db-spec {:name "john" :password "1234"}))

 (let* [db-spec__21320__auto__ db-spec] (clojure.core/with-open [con__21321__auto__ (clojure.java.jdbc/get-connection db-spec__21320__auto__)] (clojure.core/let [con-db__23557__auto__ (clojure.java.jdbc/add-connection db-spec__21320__auto__ con__21321__auto__)] (clojure.java.jdbc/insert! con-db__23557__auto__ {:name "john", :password "1234"}))))
```

But when I run :

```clj
=> (add-users {:name "john" :password "1234"})

IllegalArgumentException insert called with columns but no values  clojure.java.jdbc/insert-sql (jdbc.clj:992)
```

What's wrong with this macro? or how should I wrap and pass any number of arguments to function like `insert!` which needs the arguments flattened?

[Update]
the problem is found:
insert! needs table while in code it's not there.

> (j/insert! con-db# ~user) should be (j/insert! con-db# :users ~user)
>   (j/insert! con-db# ~@(flatten users)) should be (j/insert! con-db# :users ~@(flatten users))

But is there anyway simpler to do it?

Comment: the problem of this piece of code is found:

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this without a macro, using apply:

```
user=> (doc apply)
-------------------------
clojure.core/apply
([f args] [f x args] [f x y args] [f x y z args] [f a b c d & args])
  Applies fn f to the argument list formed by prepending intervening arguments to args.

(defn my-insert! [x & more]
  (apply jdbc/insert! db :table x more))
```

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of `clojure.java.jdbc`, you can use `insert-multi!` which accepts a sequence of hash maps for the rows:

```
(defn my-insert! [& more]
  (jdbc/insert-multi! db-spec :table more))
```

or you could just do:

```
(jdbc/insert-multi! db-spec :table [user-1 user-2 user-3])
```